# d3.js - how to draw x-axis for stacked bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I am adding an x-axis as time scale instead of the ordinal scale to the stacked bar chart with the month-year format as values. The ticks in x-axis is not aligned correctly:

My code is :

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Scanned vs Non Scanned Data</title>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/Core_functions.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/graphic_functions.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">

svg {
  width: 980px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

label {  
    display: inline-block;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    position: relative;
    padding-left:1px;  
    margin-right: 5px;  
    font-size: 13px;  
}  

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<div id="container">

<h1>Mockup of Component Scanned Mapping DV</h1>
<input type="checkbox" id = "fr">
<label for="fr">F&R</label>  

<input type="checkbox" id = "ip"> 
<label for="ip">IP&Science</label>  

<input type="checkbox" id = "ggo"> 
<label for="ggo">GGO</label>  

<input type="checkbox" id = "reuters">
<label for="reuters">Reuters</label>  

<input type="checkbox" id = "legal">
<label for="legal">Legal</label>

<br>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">


var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    p = [20, 50, 30, 20],
    //x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, w - p[1] - p[3]]),
    x = d3.time.scale().range([1, 80]);

    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h - p[0] - p[2]]),
    z = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#819FF7", "#CB491A"]),
    parse = d3.time.format("%m/%Y").parse,
    format = d3.time.format("%b-%y");

    var xAxis=d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x)
          .orient("bottom")
          .ticks(d3.time.month, 1)
              //.ticks(12)



   xAxis.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b-%y"));


    /*var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(12)
    .orient("left");*/

var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + p[3] + "," + (h - p[2]) + ")");

d3.csv("scandata.csv", function(scan) {

  // Transpose the data into layers by cause.
  var scantypes = d3.layout.stack()(["scanned", "unscanned"].map(function(scans) {
    return scan.map(function(d) {
      return {x: parse(d.date), y: +d[scans],z:d.compid,typescan:scans};
    });
  }));


  //console.log(scantypes);

  // Compute the x-domain (by date) and y-domain (by top).
  x.domain(scantypes [0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(scantypes[scantypes .length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

  // Add a group for each cause.
  var cause = svg.selectAll("g.scan")
      .data(scantypes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "scan")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
      .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(z(i)).darker(); });

  // Add a rect for each date.
  var rect = cause.selectAll("rect")
      .data(Object)
    .enter().append("svg:rect")
      .attr("id", function(d,i) { return i + " comp " + d.z;  })
      .attr("x", function(d,i) { 
                        if (i ==0) 
                        { 
                            return x(d.x) ;//+ 10
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            return x(d.x);//-5
                        }} )
      .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
      .attr("width", 30)//x.rangeBand()/2
    .on("mouseover", function(d){

                   return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
                                   .text((d.y))//d.typescan + " -  " + 
                                   .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px") 
                                   .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 20) + "px");      ;})
      .on("mousemove", function(d){

                      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
                                   .text((d.y)) //d.typescan + " -  " + 
                                   .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px") 
                                   .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 20) + "px");      ;})

      .on("mouseout", function(d){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");}) 
      .on("click", function(d){});



  var tooltip = d3.select("#container")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "visible")
    .text("Scanned vs UnScanned")
    .style("font", "Arial")
      .style("color", "white")
    .style("font-size", "14px");

  //Add x-Axis
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0,0)"; })
    .call(xAxis)




  // Add a label per date.
  var label = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(x.domain())
    .enter().append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { console.log(x.domain()/10);return eval(x(d.x)/12) ; })//x.rangeBand() / 4
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .text(format);

  // Add y-axis rules.
  var rule = svg.selectAll("g.rule")
      .data(y.ticks(5))
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "rule")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + -y(d) + ")"; });

  rule.append("svg:line")
      .attr("x2", w - p[1] - p[3])
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d ? "#fff" : "#000"; })
      .style("stroke-opacity", function(d) { return d ? .7 : null; });

  rule.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", -15)
      .style("font-family","Arial 12px")
      .attr("dy", ".25em")
      .text(d3.format(",d"));


var Rectangles = [
   { "x_axis": 870, "y_axis": -400,"color" : "#819FF7"},
   { "x_axis": 870, "y_axis": -440,"color" : "#CB491A"}];


var rectangle= svg.selectAll("#container").data(Rectangles).enter().append("rect");

var RectangleAttrb = rectangle.attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                       .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                       .attr("width",30 )
               .attr("height",20)
                       .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });


var text = svg.append('text').text('Scanned')
           .attr('x', 904)
           .attr('y', -390)
       .attr("style", "font-size: 18; font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif")
           .attr('fill', 'black')

var text = svg.append('text').text('UnScanned')
              .attr('x',904)
              .attr('y', -430)
          .attr("style", "font-size: 18; font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif")
              .attr('fill', 'black')



});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the error in this code? How do i align the x-axis labels to the bars?

My csv data is :

```
date,scanned,unscanned,compid,sbu
01/2014,10,90,101,f&r
02/2014,55,40,101,f&r
03/2014,45,23,101,f&r
04/2014,65,35,101,f&r
05/2014,100,20,101,f&r
06/2014,50,30,101,f&r
07/2014,10,90,101,f&r
08/2014,22,48,101,f&r
09/2014,0,100,101,f&r
10/2014,3,97,101,f&r
11/2014,22,60,101,f&r
12/2014,57,37,101,f&r
```

I made the following changes:

```
x = d3.time.scale().range([1, 80]);
```

Also

```
var rect = cause.selectAll("rect")
      .data(Object)
    .enter().append("svg:rect")
      .attr("id", function(d,i) { return i + " comp " + d.z;  })
      .attr("x", function(d,i) { 
                        if (i ==0) 
                        { 
                            return x(d.x) ;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            return x(d.x);
```

Comment: It looks like you're using some custom logic to determine the x position of the `rect`s. If you want the ticks to align, you have to encapsulate this in the scale so that the axis gets the same values.

Comment: How do i do that? I was referring this https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1134768 I had added the ticks in xAxis             var xAxis=d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.month, 1)

Comment: Why are you using custom logic (e.g. `x(d.x)/12`) to compute the positions of the `rect`s?

Comment: that is to align the bars actually. in the actual code it was x(d.x) but the alignment was not falling in place, hence customized it.

Comment: i have rectified it. i will edit the code. could you let me know if the approach is correct. Also i changed the domain value for the scale.

Comment: It looks fine and the ticks are working. how ever i can see <path class="domain" d="M1,6V0H800V6"></path> in the inspector which draws a black thick line, am not sure how to increase to the width of the chart.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: If your axis looks like a thick black line, it is probably just because you have default styling, which fills all shapes black.  You will want to add the CSS rule `g.axis path, g.axis line {fill:none; stroke:black; shape-rendering:crispEdges;}`.

Comment: Lars, When i added g.axis path, g.axis line {fill:none; stroke:black; shape-rendering:crispEdges;} it works fine. the issue was it was taking the default styling. it works fine now.